# How to get blog posts back to blog if post web part has been deleted in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Let's say I have a blog and delete the web part that shows the posts. How can I get this back? If I add a new web part and display the list of posts it doesn't keep the standard formatting for blog posts.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you closed it rather than deleting it (the two are different technically but appear much the same to users) you can restore it from the closed web part gallery.

If it is actually deleted you probably need to export the web part from a working site and adjust the guids in the file - SharePoint blogs aren't as customization-friendly as the other site templates.